# Reading hex data from a .bin file returns FFs at the start of the string

Tags: c++, string, hex, fstream, stringstream

I am trying to read the HEX data of a .bin file to a string. At the start of the string there is a bunch of FFs and after that the actual data starts. I want to only read the data that the .bin file contains.

This is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


std::string filePath;
std::string hexData;

std::stringstream hexStream;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter file path to the BIOS dump: ";
    std::cin >> filePath;
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), {});
    file.close();
    for (unsigned char byte : buffer) {
        hexStream << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned int>(byte);
    }
    hexData = hexStream.str();
    std::cout << hexData;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the file in a hex-editor to make sure they data you see isn't actually there? Oh, and `std::vector<unsigned char>` versus `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`?

Comment: On a different note, why the global variables?

Comment: Hard to be sure without a sample input file to test but, as hinted in the first comment, using a `std::ifstream` and the corresponding `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` maybe be a problem. Try using `std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char>`, instead (and the corresponding `unsigned char` iterator).

Comment: I tried your suggestions but none of them solve my issue. I also played around with it a little bit and I noticed if I store the data with a string in a text file it only stores the actual data. But when I std::cout the string that contains the data it also prints the FFs.